# What's the right number of cores and executors for a Spark streaming application?

Tags: apache-kafka, streaming, spark-streaming, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Spark streaming application that reads from 4 different Kafka topics and each topic has 3 partitions.
Reading operation is done in different instants (I have 4 pipelines processed in sequence) so in my idea, I need just 3 park executors (one for each partition of each topic) with one core each.
Submitting the application in this way I can see that execution is not parallelized between executor and processing time is very high respect to the complexity of the computation. What's wrong with this assumption?

If I run the same application with 4 executors with 4 cores each the execution is parallelized through all the executors and processing time is low.

I'm wondering if exists the best practices in terms of executor for topic/partition and cores while consuming from a Kafka topic with Spark Streaming.

Comment: Check your sparkUI how many partitions being read in each rdd. 
Max you can get 12 partition in each batch. In order to process all in parallel you would need 12 parallel tasks that can be achieved through 4 executor, 3 cores each.

Comment: I'm using directStream and topics are read one by one so I was thinking that 3 tasks were enough.
Strange thing is that I'm observing a different behavior running the same application on another cluster.
The second cluster is smaller than the first, it has 3 brokers instead of 4. In order to reach good performance I need to run the application with 6 executors with 1 core each and I can see that only 3 executors receive the work.
 
The described scenario could be related to the architecture of the cluster?